# PHP cron job per minute and real time

Tags: php, mysql, cron, theory

i need to build a web application that will keep update the mysql database every minute and the data will be real time on browser. 
The things i only care about is the cron job.

I was thinking if early stage the cron job need less than a minute to finish, but at late stage it might need more than a minute to complete the process. May i know that Will it crashed the process ?

Like Process A is still running, but later a minute Process B already start to run and Process A is still running. (Will it cause database data corrupted problem?)

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you took special precautions there is no mechanism that would make a process crash just because some other process gets started too, even if that second process executes the same binary or script in the file system.

Comment: You need a lock file or some other exclusive lock mechanism if you want to avoid double-running your jobs.

Comment: However there are very good reasons to _prevent_ such parallel execution, since typically such situations lead to collisions and other issues.

Comment: Since you didn't tell us the consequences of overlapping execution, nor provide any code, we don't know if it will "crash". It is a somewhat unusual application where a problem can only be solved by such frequent batch processing (IME there are other solutions most times someone proposes this as a method). Further you may experience issues with jitter running at the limit of cron's resolution. Voting to close.